# Redux state update doesn't cause rerender during parsing of large dataset

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, promise, generator

I want to get progress displayed during a large dataset being parsed (this can take a few seconds to execute). The folowing is handled inside a Promise evaluation (`.then()` calls to the browser fetch api). I created a generator function that will yield objects so I can handle the redux state change outside of the parser logic:

```
function* parseSDF(name) {
  const parser = new Parser(name, null)
  while (parser.next()) {
    // ... parsing data
    yield {...data}
  }
}
```

I then iterate over the generator (Im using typescript with the `--downlevelIteration` flag enabled) and every 50 or so iterations I want to update the state

```
const processMs = (sdf) => {
  const progress = parseSDF(sdf);

  const ms = [];
  let counter = 0;
  for (let m of progress) {
    ms.push({ ...m, id: ++counter });
    if (counter % 50 === 0) {
      setMsLoadingProgress(counter);
      console.log(counter);
    }
    setMsLoadingProgress(counter);
  }
  setMs(ms);
};
```

However, even though the console logs the progress with ~0.5 seconds between each log, react does not rerender when the redux store changes. Instead it only rerenders **once** after the parsing finishes so this is not a problem with how redux is connected to react.

1. Why does react not rerender each time I change state?
2. How can I get this to work?
3. Is there a better pattern to display progress in my UI?

Comment: what is `molecules`?

Comment: `ms`. I tried to make the snippets concise but didn't change that.